# See actual code of function in DB2 for IBM i

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, dbvisualizer, jt400

Hello guy I create a function in `DB2 UDB for AS/400` version `07.01.0000 V7R1m0`

I use a windows with dbvisualizer to connect the server.

My function is...

```
CREATE FUNCTION JVAOBJ.BNOWPAPOL(POL VARCHAR(10)) RETURNS DECIMAL(7,7) LANGUAGE SQL NOT
    DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA
    RETURN
    (
        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN NUM IN (1,2)
                THEN 0.3
                ELSE 0.19698
            END AS VALOR
        FROM
            LMDDTA.VERT240                   
        WHERE
            POLLIFE = POL )
```

It return `0.3` or `0.19698` depending of POL param

To do it I delete `DROP FUNCTION JVAOBJ.BNOWPAPOL` and run `CREATE` until work well.

My problem is **I can not see the actual code of the function** in dbvisualizer I cant see the function created

[image: dbvisualiser screnshoot]

**How I can see the actual code?**

Note:
The server administrator has access to the console as400 (yes, that black screen with green letters or orange letters, which I have not much knowledge)
maybe, I can see it from here.

Note 2:
I use [jt400 driver](http://jt400.sourceforge.net/) to connect.

Comment: You show an image from dbvis, but it's not clear if you explored it. What shows under the JVAOBJ-> Procedures node?

Comment: @user2338816 This expanded, nothing

Comment: To ensure the SQL source code is valid world-wide [such that anyone from a country who might assist, but for which their decimal separator is the comma instead of the period], for any number preceded by a comma as a separator, always include a preceding blank for the next\separate number.  For example, code 'DECIMAL(7, 7)' instead of  'DECIMAL(7,7)' and 'IN (1, 2)' instead of 'IN (1,2)'  Extremely important if the source code is _shared_ amongst developers, rather than just the compiled object(s) being shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try IBM i Navigator for web.  If it is configured on your machine, you can reach it through this URL: https://your.ibm.i:2005/ibm/console/login.do?action=secure

If it is not configured, then perhaps you can ask the admin to install the Windows client.  It is part of Client Access for Windows and is called IBM i Navigator for Windows.

In either case, use the navigation tree to go to Databases > machine > Schemas > JVAOBJ > Functions.  Right click your function > Definition and then choose Routine Body

**EDIT** Add SYSROUTINE
Another way to see the routine body is via the DB2 catalog table SYSROUTINE.  `select specific_schema, specific_name, routine_definition from sysroutine`

Comment: I check with sysadmin in `IBM i Navigator for Windows` tool in tree go to `Databases - > machine > Schemas -> QGPL` And nothing shows, also JVAOBJ item in not in tree. way to check it from the `Client Access for Windows` ?

Comment: Under SCHEMAS there should be many entries, not just QGPL.  Have the admin add JVAOBJ to the list and you will be able to see the contents of that schema.

Comment: Right click Schemas and then choose 'Select schemas to display'

Answer (score 1):

I know IBM i Navigator its a great tool, but you need some amount of knowledge to master it.

The easiest way is to query the SQL system tables using dbvisualizer

```
SELECT * FROM qsys2/sysfuncs 
WHERE (SPECIFIC_SCHEMA, SPECIFIC_NAME) = ('JVAOBJ', 'BNOWPAPOL')
```

Comment: Oh, great! the easiest way without disturbing the sysadmin